# UINavigationController flashes white when I add it to a superview

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm adding a NavigationController as a subview of my main view, with the flip animation (like a utility app/flipview thing).

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:.7];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:([self.tableController.view superview] ? UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight) forView:self.tableHostView cache:YES];



  [self.tableController.view removeFromSuperview];

  settingsView* backView1 = [[settingsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"settingsView" bundle:nil];
  backView1.delegate = self;
  UINavigationController* settingsNavStack = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:backView1];
  [backView1 release];

  settingsNavStack.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
  settingsNavStack.navigationItem.title = @"Settings";

  [self setBackView:settingsNavStack];

  [settingsNavStack release];

  [self.tableHostView addSubview:self.backView.view];
  [[self backView]setDelegate: self];
```

When it loads, the view comes in very nicely. However, the navigation bar stays white until like .2 secs after the animation finishes.

Anyone know why the navigation bar wouldn't display right away?

Answer (score 0):

Turned chacheing off, made it look a little better. But it still has the issue...